# sp_msforeachtable does not give me the right result

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, sp-msforeachtable

I want to use sp_msforeachtable to do some work for some tables in a database. I use the **IF** statement to filter the tables. But it doesn't give me the right answer. As the following script shows, I use **AdventureWorks** to do the testing. I want to do some work on every table except **Person.Address**, **Person.Contact**, **Person.CountryRegion**. As you can see, these tables still included in the result. Why? Who can help me with my problem? Great thanks.

```
sp_msforeachtable '
IF ''?'' <> ''Person.Address'' AND ''?'' <> ''Person.Contact'' AND ''?'' <> ''Person.CountryRegion''
BEGIN
    PRINT ''?''
END
';
```

The result is:

```
[Sales].[Store]
[Production].[ProductPhoto]
[Production].[ProductProductPhoto]
[Sales].[StoreContact]
[Person].[Address] <------------------------------
[Production].[ProductReview]
[Production].[TransactionHistory]
[Person].[AddressType]
[Production].[ProductSubcategory]
[dbo].[AWBuildVersion]
[Production].[TransactionHistoryArchive]
[Purchasing].[ProductVendor]
[Production].[BillOfMaterials]
[Production].[UnitMeasure]
[Purchasing].[Vendor]
[Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderDetail]
[Person].[Contact] <------------------------------
[Purchasing].[VendorAddress]
[Purchasing].[VendorContact]
[Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderHeader]
[Sales].[ContactCreditCard]
[Production].[WorkOrder]
[Person].[ContactType]
[Sales].[CountryRegionCurrency]
[Production].[WorkOrderRouting]
[Person].[CountryRegion] <------------------------------
[Sales].[CreditCard]
[Production].[Culture]
[Sales].[Currency]
[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]
[Sales].[CurrencyRate]
[Sales].[Customer]
[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
[Sales].[CustomerAddress]
[HumanResources].[Department]
[Production].[Document]
[HumanResources].[Employee]
[Sales].[SalesOrderHeaderSalesReason]
[Sales].[SalesPerson]
[HumanResources].[EmployeeAddress]
[HumanResources].[EmployeeDepartmentHistory]
[HumanResources].[EmployeePayHistory]
[Sales].[SalesPersonQuotaHistory]
[Production].[Illustration]
[Sales].[SalesReason]
[Sales].[Individual]
[Sales].[SalesTaxRate]
[HumanResources].[JobCandidate]
[Production].[Location]
[Sales].[SalesTerritory]
[Production].[Product]
[Sales].[SalesTerritoryHistory]
[Production].[ScrapReason]
[HumanResources].[Shift]
[Production].[ProductCategory]
[Purchasing].[ShipMethod]
[Production].[ProductCostHistory]
[Production].[ProductDescription]
[Sales].[ShoppingCartItem]
[Production].[ProductDocument]
[Production].[ProductInventory]
[Sales].[SpecialOffer]
[Production].[ProductListPriceHistory]
[Sales].[SpecialOfferProduct]
[Production].[ProductModel]
[Person].[StateProvince]
[Production].[ProductModelIllustration]
[dbo].[DatabaseLog]
[Production].[ProductModelProductDescriptionCulture]
[dbo].[ErrorLog]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding brackets?

```
sp_msforeachtable '
IF ''?'' <> ''[Person].[Address]'' AND ''?'' <> ''[Person].[Contact]'' AND ''?'' <> ''[Person].[CountryRegion]''
BEGIN
    PRINT ''?''
END
';
```

Comment: God, your solution works. But why? Can't we use schema name and object name in single quotes?

Comment: @Yousui: look at the output - the ms_foreachtable seems to always use brackets - so you cannot compare against something without brackets... it's just a question of string formatting.....

Comment: appart from nothing to add to that, I have nothing to add to that:)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the system tables as it appears that you want all tables not in the Person schema?

```
    select sys.schemas.name + '.' + sys.tables.name from sys.tables 
    inner join sys.schemas on sys.tables.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id 
    where sys.schemas.name <> 'Person'
```